# jquery creates inline style instead of modifying selected class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use this code to create a class dynamically.

```
 $("head").append('<style type="text/css"></style>');
 var newStyleElement = $("head").children(':last');
 newStyleElement.html('.move{transform: translateX(100px);}');
```

I than assign `move` class to an element to trigger an animation.

```
$("#element").addClass("move");
```

Later on, I would like to change the translateX value of the move class. So I get the the $(".move") and do this:

```
$(".move").css("transform","translateX(500px)");
```

This doesn't change the $(".move") translate value, but creates an inline style. Not what I want, because I want to animate back, with the removeClass option.

This is codepen to see this probelm in action. I also wrote steps to reproduce the issue. Open up inspector and you will see the inline style, when there should only be a class modification.

https://codepen.io/timsim/pen/KmNqEL

Comment: That's how css() method works and it is documented that way. Can use `removeAttr('style')` or set property value as empty string to remove it

Comment: well css() sets inline style....so working exactly how it is supposed to.

Comment: `$('.move').css()` won't change the CSS properties of `.move` - it will apply inline styles to the elements with class `.move`

Comment: That's what `css()` does. If you don't want that, define the style in a stylesheet and use `addClass()` - exactly as you did with `.move`

Comment: That's how jQuery works. Rather than create a `style` element, why not just use `.css()` to apply the same style rules? i.e. `$('.move').css('transform', 'translateX(100px)');`

Comment: Of note, for your button to add/remove a class look at `.toggleClass('move')`

Answer (score 0):

A little hacky but basically if you do the following:

JS

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  $('#element').toggleClass('move');
  $('#element').removeAttr('style');
});

$("#button-2").click(function(){
  $(".move").css("transform","translateX(500px)")
});
```

And add the following class to your CSS:

```
.move {
  transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

However you don't really want to change CSS classes like that on the fly. If you want to do something along those lines I'd recommend something like the following in JS.

```
$("head").append('<style type="text/css"></style>');
var newStyleElement = $("head").children(':last');
newStyleElement.html('.move{transform: translateX(100px);}');


$("#button").click(function(){
  $('#element').toggleClass('move');
});

$("#button-2").click(function(){
  newStyleElement.html('.move{transform: translateX(500px);}');
});
```